# Value of ScreenUpdating not changing after being set to False

Tags: vba, excel

I made a small vba script in order to turn on or off screenupdating and calculation automatic.

here is my code:

```
Sub speed_up()

    If Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = -4135
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = -4105
    End If

End Sub
```

Regarding calculation, it's working well.
In my immediate window, when I ask

```
?Application.ScreenUpdating
```

I always get

```
True
```

Is it normal? shouldn't I get false and True alternatively?

Comment: No, screen updating will turn back on when ever the code stops.

Comment: Also while these are good, they are band-aids to speeding up the code.  Using methods that limit the number of times the worksheet ranges are referenced, avoiding `.Select` and `.Activate` will do a much better job speeding up the code.

Comment: Just an FYI, you can set `Application.Calculation` using the `xlCalculationManual` constant, you don't have to set it to the 'actual' value of `-4135`

Comment: Thank you. You are correct Scott Craner but this is a small script to run when I do manual stuff on big excel files, not for other stuff involving macro.

Comment: not only _can_ you do as @Marcucciboy2 suggested, you _should_ do that. Someone (very likely you) will look at your code later and wonder what all those magic numbers are and will waste time figuring them out.

Comment: Also any time you use those kind of functions (ones that change the way that Excel responds), you need to make sure you include error handling that will reset them to what they should be.  Otherwise, if your code fails, Excel will end up in a bad state.